# replace parts of word

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep

I would like to replace words ending in `_pt` pattern (say the whole word is `X_pt`) with a new word `grid%X` which contains X, i.e. parts of the word that are not to be replaced. How do i do this with sed, grep+sed, or any other Unix tool?

The following just removes the `_pt` but does not add the `grid%`:

```
sed -i 's/_pt//g' x.f90
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow might not be the best place for your question.

Comment: I am looking for a one line regex command not code. So far i am stuck on how to keep the parts of the word that are not replaced (X in my example).

Comment: How is "a one line regex command" not "code"? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+?)_pt\b/grid%\1/g' file
```

Note that the `-i` option is also available, for modifying the file in-place and optionally saving the old one with the extension provided.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` like this:

```
sed -i -E "s/(.*?)_pt\b/grid%\1/g" file.txt
```

What this does is the following:

- `(.*?)` matches and groups any character but `?` denotes nongreedy method of matching.
- `\b` ensures it is the end of the word.
- `\1` stands for first group, which in our case is everything before `'_pt'`.

**Comment:** `sed` and `awk` are manipulators, `grep` is just search-like thing, meaning it cannot replace strings.

> BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK!! Why? Because neither basic nor extended posix regex recognizes `?` as escape for greedy search. Instead use perl:

```
perl -pe 's|(*?)_pt\b|grid%\1|g'
```

Comment: This is close but not working quite the way i want it. An example:
-!$acc update device(msfu_pt, msfv_pt, msft_pt)
+grid%!$acc update device(msfu_pt, msfv_pt, msft)
I guess it takes the whole line as a word.

Comment: When does it fail?

Comment: `.*?` won't work in `sed`. It will work as greedy `.*` and will match longest match before last `_pt`

Comment: You probably want something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` rather than `.*`

Comment: @campovski: Yeah, but you've still got the "_pt" in the regexp, so I think that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Indeed it is, I thougth you wanted to substitute whole regex string with that, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `gnu sed` command with word boundaries:

```
sed -E 's/\b([_[:alnum:]]+)_pt\b/grid%\1/g' file
```

Presence of `\b` on either side of the pattern ensures that we match full words only that end with `_pt`.

If you are on OSX and don't have `gnu sed` installed then use:

```
sed -E 's/[[:<:]]([_[:alnum:]]+)_pt[[:>:]]/grid%\1/g' file
```

Comment: Being on macOS and not having GNU sed are not as tied as your text implies. One may be on that system and have the program installed, or use a completely different system and not have it installed either :)

Comment: `One may be on that system and have the program installed` - That is what I implied as I am on OSX and have `gnu sed` installed using `home brew`